# c++ simple while loop that doesnt loop

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int number;
  using namespace std;

  cout<<"write number between 1 and 10:"<<endl;
  cin>>number;

  if (number<=10 && number>=1)
    cout<<"correct!"<< endl;
  else
    do{
      cout<<"wrong! new number:"<<endl;
      cin>>number;
    }
    while(number>10 && number<1);
}
```

The loop only goes once and ends directly :( i want it to go endlessly until condition is met. Im very new to c++ so any help is appreciated :)

Comment: `number>10 && number<1` This condition can never possibly be true. There is no number that is simultaneously greater than 10 and less than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your while condition is wrong, it should be `or` instead of `and` there ( `||` instead of `&&` in your case). To avoid such errors and make code cleaner try to avoid repeating code, ie code that literally or logically does the same. In your code you input from `cin` twice and you check for condition twice as well:

```
int number = 0;
while( true ) {
    cout << "Enter number between 1 and 10:";
    cin >> number;
    if( number >= 1 && number <= 10 )
        break;
    cout << "invalid number, try again" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The while condition is clearly not correct.
A variable that is>10 *and* <1 does not exists.
Try to put a || instead of the && in the condition first.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> int main() { int number; using namespace std; cout<<"write number between 1 and 10:"<<endl; cin>>number; if (number<=10 && number>=1) cout<<"correct!"<< endl; else do{ cout<<"wrong! new number:"<<endl; cin>>number; } while(number<10 && number>1); }
```

Your while condition isn't right and I've fixed that.
Your condition isn't met even once
Due to do while task is done before checking condition.